# Envers configuration with hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: hibernate-envers, hibernate.cfg.xml

I am trying to use Envers to audit the updates/inserts into my tables. I have created audit tables with extension _AUDIT in the DB.

But when I actually run the application, I dont see any entries in the audit tables. I even have no errors or exceptions thrown. Entries are being inserted into the main tables but the AUDIT tables are not updated.

Here is my ENVERS configuration :

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<!-- Hibernate ENVERS Configuration -->
<property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix">_AUDIT</property>
<property name="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name">REVISION_ID</property>
<property name="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name">REVTYPE</property>
<property name="org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field">true</property>
<property name="org.hibernate.envers.default_schema">ROCC</property>



<!-- Hibernate ENVERS Listener Configuration -->

<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-insert"/>
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-update"/>
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-delete"/>
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="pre-collection-update"/>
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="pre-collection-remove"/>
<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-collection-recreate"/>
```

My table is as follows:

```
/**
* Transaction generated by hbm2java
*/
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSACTION", schema = "ROCC")
public class TransactionTable implements java.io.Serializable{...}
```

The Audit table is TRANSACTION_AUDIT in the same schema.

Can any one tell me why the auditing is not working?

Comment: What versions of Envers / Hibernate are you using? They should match to get them working correctly.